# If all principal minors of a matrix are $1$ then it has an elementary row.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. The $i^\text{ th}$ row of $A$ is said to be elementary if it has a $1$ in the $i$th position and $0$ everywhere else. I am trying to prove the following theorem :

> **Theorem :** Let $R$ be a commutative integral domain with unity and let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $R$. Suppose that every proper principal minor of $A$ is $1$ . Then $\text{det }A$ is $1$ if and only if $A$ has an elementary row.

**Attempt at proof :** If $A$ has an elementary row then calculating the determinant along that row we can easily see $\text{det }A=1$.

I am stuck with the reverse -

If $\text{det }A=1$ and suppose $A$ has no elementary rows. The first row of $A$ will look like $(1,a_{12},a_{13},\cdots,a_{1n})$ where at least one $a_{1i}\neq0$. So $$\text{det }A=1+(-1)^{i_1+1}a_{1i_1}\,\text{det }A_{1i_1}+(-1)^{i_2+1}a_{1i_2}\,\text{det }A_{1i_2}+\cdots+(-1)^{i_r+1}a_{1i_r}\,\text{det }A_{1i_r}$$ 
where $a_{1i_j}\neq0$ for $1\leq j\leq r$ and $A_{1i_j}$ is the submatrix obtained from $A$ by deleting the first row and the $i_j^\text{ th}$ column.

If I can somehow show that $(-1)^{i_1+1}a_{1i_1}\,\text{det }A_{1i_1}+(-1)^{i_2+1}a_{1i_2}\,\text{det }A_{1i_2}+\cdots+(-1)^{i_r+1}a_{1i_r}\,\text{det }A_{1i_r}\neq0$ then I will be done but I am unsure how to.

If there is a better way to prove this result then please let me know.

Thank you.